# Do we produce Vitamin D in the shade?

Tags: dermatology, micronutrients, vitamin-d, uv-rays

Do our bodies produce Vitamin D in the shade?

If so, what is the percentage decrease in the amount of Vitamin D produced compared to full exposure to sunlight?

For example, sitting outside in the sun will result in the production of x units of Vitamin D.  If the same person then sits under an umbrella, what percentage of x (if any) will they produce?

Answer (score 10):

The exact value depends on a lot of things - skin tone, the time of day, latitude,  how deep the shade is,...

The study [Vitamin D effective ultraviolet wavelengths due to scattering in shade](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960076005002220) found that the UVB radiation at 280–320 nanometers that is needed for vitamin D production dropped to levels at around 50% in a tree shade and under an umbrella. It was much less on a covered veranda - around 11% - and completely absent in a car with closed windows.

[Latitudinal Variations over Australia of the Solar UV-Radiation Exposures for Vitamin D<sub>3</sub> in Shade Compared to Full Sun](http://www.bioone.org/doi/10.1667/RR1951.1?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dpubmed&) came to similar conclusions (emphasis mine):

> Using shade for UV<sub>D3</sub> exposures can reduce total UV-radiation exposure by **37% to 58%** compared to full sun UV<sub>D3</sub> exposures. This research indicates that an improved approach to optimize UV-radiation exposures for the production of vitamin D<sub>3</sub> is to use diffuse UV radiation under shade in and around the middle of the day.

Since exposure to these wavelengths is what drives vitamin D production, an approximate answer to your question is probably "around 35 to 55%".

Answer (score 6):

About 1/4 - it varies with the reflectivity of the surface, and angle of the sun. Detailed study is at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20199222

Comment: Hello, welcome to Health.SE. This seems like it could be a very good answer, but it lacks explanation. Could you please go into more detail? Also, your reference doesn't seem to be extremely reliable as it is a wiki. Could you possibly try to find better, more reliable sources. See [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/184/is-wikipedia-a-reliable-source) and [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources?lq=1) for more on that. Thanks :)

Comment: Edited to replace wiki link with a more reliable source for the study.